# Getting Different column values from Multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in SQL Server tables:

```
id  Sal
1   100
2   200

id  Wages
1   600
2   800
```

I want the output as following:

```
id   Sal/Wages
1    100
1    600
2    200
2    800
```

How I can do that using a SELECT statement in SQL Server?

Comment: I'm not totally sure if I got the question, but have you looked into the `UNION` and the `ORDER BY` statement?

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
Select Id, sal as [sal/wages]
from table1
UNION ALL
Select Id, wages as [sal/wages]
from table2
Order by id,[sal/wages]
```

If you don't need duplicate records then just use `UNION`

Answer (score 1):

use [union all](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

```
select id, sal as [sal/Wages] from table1
union all
select id, wages as [sal/Wages] from table2
order by 1
```

Note that I've used `union all` and not `union`, because union removes duplicates from resulting set. Sometimes it might be useful, but not in your case, I think.